# linear equations with inequality constraints

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

The problem is, given a set of linear equations $Ax=b$ such that the system is under-determined, and a set of linear inequalities $Cx\geq 0$, find a solution for the system. Does anyone know a general approach to deal with such problem?

Comment: Simplex Method.

Comment: In the Simplex Method, can we have real numbers (not integers) as $C$ members?

Comment: Yes. In fact, Simplex is simpler for real numbers than integers.